# Системы управления сетью с архитектурой «менеджер-агенты»

Tags: ssh, архитектура, администрирование, snmp

Пишу пояснительную записку к дипломному проекту.
В первом разделе описываю что из себя представляет администрирование компьютерных сетей. Рассказал про архитектуру систем управления сетью "менеджер–агенты". Потом привел примеры реализации этой архитектуры: SNMP, CMIP.

**Вопрос**: является ли такие протоколы как ssh, telnet, rdp системами управления сетью с архитектурой "менеджер-агенты"?

Например, можно на все машины в сети установить ssh сервера, которые будут агентами, а ssh клиент на машине администратора будет менеджером.

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, текст или ссылку на используемые вами определения терминов «система управления сетью» и «архитектура "менеджер-агент"».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8#.D0.90.D1.80.D1.85.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D1.83.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F

Answer (score 1):

Все перечисленное вами - средства удаленного управления. Их можно использовать для построения, как централизованной системы управления (агент-менеджер, клиент-сервер), так и распределенной. То что админ может подключиться к любой машине с со своего рабочего места само по себе не отменяет того, что на каждой машине будет своя учетная запись администратора и каждую из машин в сети ему придется настраивать отдельно. Но при этом ни кто не запрещает подключиться по тому же SSH, например, к RADIUS серверу или контроллеру Cisco и поменять настройки всех WiFi точек разом, не заходя на каждую из них в отдельности. Используя, приведенный вами в качестве примера, протокол SNMP, можно построить систему централизованного управления и мониторинга, но сам по себе он таковой системой не является.

Суть централизованной системы управления в том, что управление всеми подчиненными узлами сети осуществляется одним или группой серверов. Т.е. вы вносите изменения параметров на сервере, а агенты их самостоятельно (или после пинка от сервера) подхватывают и применяют. При этом практически не важно какие протоколы для этого будут использоваться, т.к. это зависит от задач, решаемых конкретной системой управления. Система управления - это комплекс мер и средств, но ни как один конкретный протокол или технология.

Если уж приводить пример централизованного управления - то как вариант ActiveDirectory и/или *nix-аналоги с полноценным управлением всеми станциями в подчиненной сети, централизованную настройку параметров ОС и т.д., или того же Касперского с его агентами и сервером администрирования. Если не стоит жестких требований по конкретным решениям - смотрите в сторону известных брендов MS, HP, Cisco, Citrix и т.д., у них, как правило, есть довольно подробные описания архитектурных решений из которых вполне можно сделать выжимку для диплома.